# Selecting column values with rowname using a vector in R

Tags: r

data frame

```
row.names   probes  Symbols Entrez_IDs
2315554 2315554 NA  NA
2315633 2315633 B3GALT6 126792
2315674 2315674 SCNN1D  6339
2315739 2315739 NA  NA
2315894 2315894 VWA1    64856
2315918 2315918 NA  NA
2315951 2315951 NA  NA
2316218 2316218 CALML6  163688
```

Vector

```
v = c("SCNN1D", "CALML6", "VWA1")
```

If i want to search "Symbols" column, How can i get this result:

New data frame

```
row.names  Symbols
2315674 SCNN1D  
2315894 VWA1    
2316218 CALML6
```

I tried `df[,df$Symbols %in% v]`

Can anyone help?

Comment: `df1[df1$Symbols %in% v,c(1,3)]`

Answer (score 2):

assuming you data is `df` you can try this

```
with(df, df[Symbols %in% v, ])
row.names  probes Symbols Entrez_IDs
3   2315674 2315674  SCNN1D       6339
5   2315894 2315894    VWA1      64856
8   2316218 2316218  CALML6     163688
```

Or

```
subset(df, Symbols %in% v)
```

Comment: it gives the below error: `Error in rma$Symbols %in% ff : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': Error in rma$Symbols : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: Why would you use `$` if you calling only one column?

Comment: `subset(df, Symbols %in% v)` seems a bit more compact

Comment: @aliocee Hmm.. I should have posted that as an answer :-)

Comment: @arkan can i make it unique, because i am having repetition in the columns